# Instance initializer unreachable after second call to class

Tags: java

```
private static final List<String> abasicWordList = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("abject");
    add("aberration");
    add("abjure");
    add("abnegation");
    add("abrogate");
    add("abscond");
    add("abstruse");
    add("accede");
}};

public static List<String> getabasicWordList(){return abasicWordList;}
```

From a different class

```
Alist.getabasicWordList();
```

I'd like to reference this List more than once but for some reason the instance initializer returns an empty list after the first time.  What could be the problem?

Comment: Please include code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You emptied the list. Wrap it in a call to Collections.unmodifiableList to ensure that you can’t change the constant list.

Comment: Slightly off-topic - You may find `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(String ...))` a better choice than double brace initialization.

Comment: I'd like to keep the syntax the same.  Cool idea though.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue could be. On other apps I've built it works well.  Android studio is not my amigo tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure why you get errors. I did the following, I initialised it twice, and both times I get 'abject' printed out.

```
class Alist {
    public Alist() {}

    private static final List<String> abasicWordList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("abject");
        add("aberration");
        add("abjure");
        add("abnegation");
        add("abrogate");
        add("abscond");
        add("abstruse");
        add("accede");
    }};

    public static List<String> getabasicWordList() {
        return abasicWordList;
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> first = Alist.getabasicWordList();
        System.out.println(first.get(0));

        List<String> second = Alist.getabasicWordList();
        System.out.println(second.get(0));
    }
}
```